# how to add columns to Kendo Grid that is filled with remote data?

Tags: javascript, gridview, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

So I have this view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head >
    <link href="<%: Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.common.min.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="<%: Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.default.min.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title><%: ViewBag.GestionTitle %></title>
</head>
    <body>


        <h1><%: ViewBag.GestionTitle %></h1>
        <div id="usuariosGrid"></div>
        <button id="addUsuario" type="button" class="k-input"><%: ViewBag.Agregar %></button>

        <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")%>"></script>
        <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.web.min.js")%>"></script>
        <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/usuario/usuario.js")%>"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The div usuariosGrid is filled with remote data with the following function:

```
$(function () {
    var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:81/SismosService.svc/usuario/index",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: "Response"
        },
    });
    $("#usuariosGrid").kendoGrid({
        columns: ["UsuarioId", "Nombre", "ApellidoP", "ApellidoM"],
        dataSource: ds
    });
});
```

This creates a grid with the columns specified in the function. Now what I want to do is for every row inserted also to add a column with two hyperlinks, one that would redirect me to an Edit page and another one that would redirect me to a Delete page.

How can I do this? I've looked for examples but haven't been able to find anything that resembles what I'm trying to achieve. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you have to add a column to the [`columns`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#columns-array) definition of your `kendoGrid`. This new cell will contain the links (or even some buttons).

For this you would probably be interested on using [`columns.template`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#columnstemplate-string) field where you can merge HTML with variable data, for example, data from row that you editing or deleting.

Instead of a link you might define a custom action by doing something like:

```
columns : [
    ...
    { command: { text: "Edit", click: editRecord }, title: " ", width: "140px" }
]
```

and in `editRecord` you can do whatever you want (see KendoUI example [here](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/custom-command.html)).

Comment: Amazing, it's exactly what I was looking for, but I see that if I use the command property, every command is placed in a different column, is there a way to place several buttons on the same cell? or that can only be done with templates? I'm new to Kendo UI and I haven't gotten the hang of it just yet. Hope you can help me.

Comment: Yes, there is :-) [`columns.command`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#columnscommand-stringarray) can be both an object or an array of objects. Use `command: [ { text: "Edit", click : editRecord }, { text: "Delete", click: deleteRecord } ], title: " ", width: "140px" }`

Comment: many thanks, finally I just want to know how can I access to the row I clicked, I tried to check the e object that is sent to the function I defined but it has a lot of stuff

Comment: `this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));`

Comment: thank you so much, it's hard being new to a framework, thanks again for your help

Comment: Ha sido un placer poder ayudarte!